# How to check syntax error in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am not familiar with coffee script, I try to move jquery from view to put in asset but not able to make it work.

Here the working from view:

```
- jquery_ready do
  $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
  $( "#voucher_voucher_provider_id" ).change(function() {
  var exist_id = $(this).val();
  var ids = $('#voucher_false_ids_')[0].value;
  if(jQuery.inArray(exist_id, ids.split(" ")) !== -1){
  $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
  }
  else
  {
  $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').show();
  }
  });
```

Then in /app/assets/javascript/mycode.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
  $( "#voucher_voucher_provider_id" ).change ->
    exist_id = $(this).val();
    ids = $('#voucher_false_ids_')[0].value;
    alert('alert');
    If(jQuery.inArray(exist_id, ids.split(" ")) !== -1)
      $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
    else
      $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').show();
```

So far, I able to run until .change ->
alert('alert');
Not after I start put all line after If

which cause error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /admin
SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:51: unexpected =
```

Help: for proper syntax or what is the error coming from /Thanks

Comment: Two things jump out: `If` should be `if` and `!==` should be `!=`. Or just leave the JavaScript as JavaScript.

Comment: It worked, would you please move you comment to answer for me to accept / Thanks

Comment: Feel free to go with Alex's answer, his answer has more details than my quick comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste that snippet into [the "Try CoffeScript" page](https://coffeescript.org/#try:jQuery%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24(%27label%5Bfor%3Dvoucher_name%5D%2C%20input%23voucher_name%27).hide()%3B%0A%20%20%24(%20%22%23voucher_voucher_provider_id%22%20).change%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20exist_id%20%3D%20%24(this).val()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20ids%20%3D%20%24(%27%23voucher_false_ids_%27)%5B0%5D.value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%27alert%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20If(jQuery.inArray(exist_id%2C%20ids.split(%22%20%22))%20!%3D%3D%20-1)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%27label%5Bfor%3Dvoucher_name%5D%2C%20input%23voucher_name%27).hide()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24(%27label%5Bfor%3Dvoucher_name%5D%2C%20input%23voucher_name%27).show()%3B) of the CoffeeScript website, it tells you what's wrong.

It says this:

```
[stdin]:7:51: error: unexpected =
    If(jQuery.inArray(exist_id, ids.split(" ")) !== -1)
                                                  ^
```

CoffeeScript does not have `===` or `!==` operators. `==` and `!=` are translated their strict equivalents when compiled for you.

If you fix that, you get another error:

```
[stdin]:8:1: error: unexpected indentation
      $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
^^^^^^
```

This is because of the previous line. You start an `if` statement with `If`, so CoffeeScript does not see this as an `if` statement, but instead as a function call to the `If()` function.

Change that to lowercase `if` and then it compiles just fine.

---

Short version, here it is fixed:

```
jQuery ->
  $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
  $( "#voucher_voucher_provider_id" ).change ->
    exist_id = $(this).val();
    ids = $('#voucher_false_ids_')[0].value;
    alert('alert');
    if(jQuery.inArray(exist_id, ids.split(" ")) != -1)
      $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').hide();
    else
      $('label[for=voucher_name], input#voucher_name').show();
```

Comment: `If(jQuery.inArray(exist_id, ids.split(" ")) !== -1)` is actually treated as a function call in both coffescript and JS. And yes JS will actually let you define a function named `If`.